# Should i include /public in Vue.js gitignore?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, gitignore, public

I have a laravel/Vue.js project, and whenever i commit there are 3 files that get committed too:
-`public/main.js`
-`public/manifest.js`
-`public/vendor.js`

so, Should i include /public in Vue.js gitignore?

Comment: No you don't commit those files. They are automatically generated (and overwritten) when you run `npm run prod|dev|watch`

Comment: okay so i should include them in .gitignore. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your workflow and project setup:

- if you are working alone you can build assets locally and upload on
  production. It will save you space from node_modules on your server
- if you are working with someone else it is good to be ignored to skip
  the conflicts on merging (not big deal, but annoying)
- there is some
  setups for zero-downtime deploy where each release is in new
  directory. In this case you don't want node_modules in each release
  and wait to be build. Then you shouldn't ignore them.
- the same case
  will be if you are using some continues integration tool to test
  frontend

Comment: The problem is that `npm run dev|watch`  and `npm run prod` produce differently optimised files so if you do commit then you lock yourself to one or the other.

Comment: When we worked with zero-downtime deploy we ran npm prod before each commit. Probably it can be automated with hooks. It really depends on how the project and team is working

Comment: It's more sensible is to automate it as part of the deployment which can happen anywhere and not necessarily on the destination server. Source control should be for source not for transpiled or compiled files. At the very least if you are to commit compiled files put them in a tag and not in the main branch

Comment: @katsarov i am working with a team and having these files makes working in parallel impossible since we always have conflicts. so i guess it is safe to add them to.gitignore